# Time a user spent online using wtmp

Tags: c, authentication, time, logout

While using wtmp, i was able to get the tty of the user login, the time of login and more information. however, I want to be able to know how much time the user spent online. Is there a way to get the logout time ?

Thanks,

```
#define WTMP "/var/log/wtmp"
#define K               1024

int main()
{
 struct utmp w;
 FILE *fd;
 time_t t;
 struct tm *timeinfo;
 char buffer[K];

 fd = fopen(WTMP, "r");

 if(fd == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", WTMP);
    exit(0);
 }

 while(fread(&w, sizeof(struct utmp), 1, fd) == 1) {
    if(w.ut_type == USER_PROCESS) {
        if( strcmp(w.ut_user, "user1") == 0) {

        /* get time in seconds, convert to struct tm, make printable formate*/
        t = w.ut_tv.tv_sec;
        timeinfo = localtime (&t);

        strftime (buffer, K, "%a %b %e %R (EST)", timeinfo);
        printf("time: %s  Login tty: %s\n", buffer, w.ut_line);

        }
    }
 } 
 fclose(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code of the "last" command, which you can download from http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sysvinit/sysvinit_2.88dsf.orig.tar.gz (once you have the download, unpack it and check sysvinit-2.88dsf/src/last.c):

```
    case USER_PROCESS:
        /*
         *  This was a login - show the first matching
         *  logout record and delete all records with
         *  the same ut_line.
         */
        c = 0;
        for (p = utmplist; p; p = next) {
            next = p->next;
            if (strncmp(p->ut.ut_line, ut.ut_line,
                UT_LINESIZE) == 0) {
                /* Show it */
                if (c == 0) {
                    quit = list(&ut, p->ut.ut_time,
                        R_NORMAL);
                    c = 1;
                }
                if (p->next) p->next->prev = p->prev;
                if (p->prev)
                    p->prev->next = p->next;
                else
                    utmplist = p->next;
                free(p);
            }
        }
        /*
         *  Not found? Then crashed, down, still
         *  logged in, or missing logout record.
         */
        if (c == 0) {
            if (lastboot == 0) {
                c = R_NOW;
                /* Is process still alive? */
                if (ut.ut_pid > 0 &&
                    kill(ut.ut_pid, 0) != 0 &&
                    errno == ESRCH)
                    c = R_PHANTOM;
            } else
                c = whydown;
            quit = list(&ut, lastboot, c);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm fairly new to this stuff. I tried ut_line and I got the tty of the login/logout, does that mean each 2 identical tty are the login and logout ?

Comment: Yes - once a user logs in to a tty, this tty is "blocked" by the user, so the only thing that can happen to it is the user logging out again. Of course, if the system crashes, or the hard disk has write errors, or the user just doesn't log out, you won't see any logout record. That's what the second part (after the comment) is for.

Comment: I tried ut_line to get the logout/login time. However, i get many tty that have not been closed, although the user is not logged in.

Comment: Run the "last" command on your system. Compare its output with your program. If the standard last command says still logged in as well, then something is happening in your system that prevents the logout records from being written. If the output of last shows a logout time, check why your program ignores the corresponding wtmp record.

Comment: apparently there is no 2identical tty to indicate login/logout.
There is a logout/login for each tty. Part of the "last" output:
user1  pts/3    Sat Dec  7 14:14   still logged in 
              .........
user1  pts/18   Sat Dec  7 14:01 - 14:13  (00:12).     
have any idea on how to get the logout time, if i already know the tty and login time ?